# How to empty table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I cant delete the row contents of a table, but what if I want to delete the rows too?

My Javascript code: (I want all the rows to disappear except the first one.)

```js
function deleteAll() {
        for ( var i = 0; i <= table.rows.length; i++){
            table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = "";
            table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = "";
            table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = "";            
        }     
        
    }
```

My HTML table:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tab tab-1">
            <table id="table" border="1">
                <th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </th>
                <tr>
                    <td>Frank</td>
                    <td>Nenjim</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Alex</td>
                    <td>Ferreira</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                </tr>


            </table>      

        </div>
        <div class="tab tab-2">
            First Name :<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
            Last Name :<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">
            Age :<input type="number" name="age" id="age">

            <button onclick="deleteAll()">Delete All</button>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="tableEdit.js"></script>
</body>
```

So, the Javascript code above doesn't satisfy me because I want only the first row to remain. I don't want empty rows.

Comment: `while( table.rows.length > 1) table.rows[1].remove();`

Comment: Your table html is invalid btw. Th is not a row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery `remove()` function as described in this [example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Delete-all-rows-from-Table-except-First-Header-row-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx) to delete all rows except the (first) header row:

```
$('#table tr:not(:first)').remove();
```

You may instead want to delete just the rows of body section (inside `<tbody>`) as mentioned in this [post](https://forums.asp.net/post/4506340.aspx):

```
$('#table > tbody > tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 1;i<table.rows.length;){
            table.deleteRow(i);
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to remove data rows only then use

```
$("#table tr").remove();
```

And if you want to empty table with header then use

```
$("#table").empty();
```

Comment: Both of these commands would eliminate the header if you have header rows assigned by `<tr>`

Comment: Header row should have **<th></th>**  tag or it should have `<table><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody><tr></tr></tbody><table>` and you can use **$("#table tbody tr").remove();** to remove data row.